# colorize a word by entering its rank number

Tags: jquery, colors, textcolor

please, how can I colorize a word by entering its rank number using jQuery?

example:

```
<div id="example">
<p class="txt">hello my best friend</p>
<input type="number" id="myNumber">
<button>Color it</button>
</div>
```

when I enter (2,3) and press the button, the words "my" and "best" become yellow (#ffbe00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gL88q17m/810/)

```js
(function ($) {
   
var SetColor=function(){   
    var str=$(".txt").text().split(' ');
    $(".txt").empty();
    var filter=$("#myNumber").val().replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',');
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){

       for(var j=0;j<filter.length;j++){
        if((i+1)==filter[j]){        
            str[i]="<span style='color: yellow;'>"+str[i]+"<span>";           
            }
       }    
    $(".txt").append(str[i]+" ");
    
    } 
} 

$("#btn").on("click",SetColor);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
<p class="txt">hello my best friend</p>
<input type="text" id="myNumber">
<button id="btn">Color it</button>
</div>
```